# Is it possible to get the full page html when using React/Enzyme/Jest with Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, next.js

I've got a React component that looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';

export default class extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    language: 'en',
    country: 'us'
  };

  ...

  render () {
    const language = this.props.language || 'en';
    const country = this.props.country || 'us';

    return (
      <div className="edf-header">
        <div  className="desktop-header"></div>
        <div  className="mobile-header"></div>

        <Head>
          <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `
            var secure = "//local-www.hjjkashdkjfh.com";
            var perfConfig = {
              LOCALE: '${language}_${country}',
```

I want to confirm, via a test, that the `perfConfig` is built correctly. I'm testing it with:

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Foo from '../../components/Foo';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import enzymify from 'expect-enzyme';
import Head from 'next/head';

const {mount, shallow, render} = Enzyme;
Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
expect.extend(enzymify());

...

  it('renders correct nsgConfig', () => {
    const foo = render(<Foo country='ca' language='fr'/>);
    console.dir(foo.html());
    expect(foo.find('Head')).toExist();
    expect(foo.html().indexOf("LOCALE: 'fr_ca'")).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
```

The problem is that the html doesn't contain a head tag. The html has the divs but that's it.

How do I get Next/Enzyme to work together here to render the full page? Tried shallow and mount with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Head component adds its children to the actual  once the page is mounted. You would have to render the full page starting from the _document component. In my tests mount seems to be using a "div" tag where it inserts the component and complains if you actually mount a "head" component so I'm not sure this is even possible.